# triangle with border with pure css

Tags: html, css

I need to build a message holder with a tip in the form of triangle with border. I've managed to build the tip [using two triangles](http://jsfiddle.net/3zDrz/):

```
#triangle-border {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 100px 80px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #edb2b7 transparent;
}
#triangle-content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;    
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 100px 80px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #F9EDEF transparent;
}
```

I believe it can be done with one HTML object, I just can't figure out how. Can you please help?

I've added the example of the message container that I'm trying to build

[image]

Comment: and what should the final result look like compared to your fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3zDrz/1/)**. `:after` and `:before` are called pseudo elements.

```
<div id="message-holder"></div>
```

---

```
#message-holder {
    margin-top:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #F9EDEF;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #edb2b7;
}

#message-holder:before,#message-holder:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:-24px;
    left:25px;
    border-bottom:25px solid #f9edef;
    border-left:25px solid transparent;
    border-right:25px solid transparent;
}
#message-holder:before{
    top:-25px;
    border-bottom-color:#edb2b7;
}
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you very much! It seems complicated though. I'd need to understand how this works so I can mold it into the form on the image that I uploaded. Can you please provide a short description? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sure. Now this is a very rough explanation because I am bad at explaining things. Pseudo elements as the name suggests do not actually exist in the dom. There are many pseudo elements like `:after` `:before` `:firs-letter`.

Comment: Here is a great [tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) on how to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also provide code for the tip alone? In case I don't figure out how you build the message wrapper with one element I'll be able to use just the tip implementation.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by code for tip alone ? That whole css creates your tip message box.

Comment: This code also creates the message wrapper itself. Please check the image I uploaded where with the green rectangular I showed what I meange by the `tip`.

Comment: Here is an update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/3zDrz/2/) which is close to what you want. Now as they are pseudo elements, they cannot exist on their own without the `#message-holder`

Comment: In case you just need the tip replace `#message-holder` by any other class or id in ever `#message-holder:before` or `#message-holder:after`

Comment: Can you please also tell me what this property  `-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);` does ?

Comment: Thos combined with absolute positioning and `left:50%` creates absolute centering! No matter how wide your message holder is, tip is going to be centered.

Comment: See, when we use `left:50%` the left starts from the starting of the tip and if you add tip's width to it, it doesn't really center but is a bit to the right side. `-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);` pushes the tip to `-50%` of it's total width. You can use similar concept for vertical middle alignment too.

Comment: Check this [pen](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/GKcem). It has multiple vertical alignment options.